# How to manipulate only certain element belonging to an object list in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame in which several columns contain list of object like the following:

```
Index       A             B                  C
0       [1,2,3,]    [4,5,6,...20]      [1,2,3,...,64]
1       [1,2,3,]    [4,5,6,...20]      [1,2,3,...,64]
..
..
n       [1,2,3,]    [4,5,6,...20]      [1,2,3,...,64]
```

Of course numbers are just for reference. I would like to sum, let's say '10' to the first
32 values of the column 'C'. I tried to use apply fucntion with lambda in several ways without success. Could you help me?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear whether you want to:

- add 10 to all elements inside the lists in the first 32 rows of column C;
- add 10 to the first 32 elements of all lists of column C.

Both can be accomplished using `apply` with a lambda returning a list comprehension.

The former:

```
df.loc[0:32, 'C'] = df.loc[0:32, 'C'].apply(lambda lst: [x+10 for x in lst])
```

The latter:

```
df.C = df.C.apply(lambda lst: [x+10 if i < 32 else x for i, x in enumerate(lst)])
```

Comment: Thanks man! You were so fast! Sorry for the misunderstanding, you are right. Actually i would like to add 10 to the first 32 elements of column C for all rows. So i think the right way Is the second!

Comment: No big deal, you got two answers for the price of one ;-)